# How can I get the index of an item added to a Backbone collection via fetch?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I’ve got a Backbone Collection. I’m using `fetch({add:true})` to fetch new items from my server, and add them to the collection.

I’ve bound a listener function to the collection’s `add` event. I’d like that function to get the index at which the item was added to the collection.

[Backbone’s documentation for `Collection.add`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Collection-add) says “if you're a callback listening to a collection's `"add"` event, `options.index` will tell you the index at which the model is being added to the collection.”

I’ve logged the arguments that seem to be passed to my listener function to the console and had a look at them. As far as I can tell, the first argument is the item added, followed by a temporary collection object created to hold it when it came back from the server. I don’t seem to have an object with an `index` property.

How can I get the index at which the item was added to the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To anybody reading this in the future, NOTE: since version 0.9.9, options.index is no longer set. From the changelog:

> To improve the performance of add, options.index will no longer be set in the `add` event callback. `collection.indexOf(model)` can be used to retrieve the index of a model as necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Check the third argument to your bind function, it should contain the index property

```
var c=new Backbone.Collection();
c.bind("add",function(model,collection,opts){
    console.log(opts);
});

c.add({});
c.add({});
```

Edit : I just checked Backbone 0.5.3 and it would seem `options.index` is only available in version 0.9

Comment: Aha! Yes, of course — I had looked at the third argument, but I’d assumed it was something else as the index was set to zero. I’d forgotten that I’d only been testing adding an item to an empty collection, so obviously the index would be zero. Excellent, cheers.